# SAP NetWeaver RFC - How to fetch data from RFC

Tags: c#, .net

I have no previous experience of fetching data from SAP. From github example I'm trying to learn how the SAP NetWeaver RFC works, but I find it difficult to fetch the data. Can somebody help me, how to get the data from the function.

Thank you in advance.

```
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;

        // Connect WTIH SAP NetWeaver
        string connectionString = "AppServerHost=****; SystemNumber=**; User=*******; Password=*******; Client=***; Language=EN; PoolSize=*; Trace=*";

        var connection = new SapConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Connect();

        bool connOk= connection.IsValid;
        if (connOk)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection established.");
        }

        if (connection.Ping())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection is alive");
        }


        var functionMetadata = connection.GetFunctionMetadata("Z_DEQ_STAFF_TIME");
        var functionName = functionMetadata.GetName();
        Console.WriteLine($"Function name: {functionName}");

        var parameterCount = functionMetadata.Parameters.Count();
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Parameters: {parameterCount}");

        foreach(var parameterMetaData in functionMetadata.Parameters)
        {
            var parameterName = parameterMetaData.Name;
            var parameterType = parameterMetaData.Type;
            Console.WriteLine(parameterName, parameterType);
        }
        functionMetadata.Parameters.TryGetValue("WERKS", out var parameterNameMetadata);


        var someFunction = connection.CreateFunction("Z_DEQ_STAFF_TIME");
        var result = someFunction.Invoke<Employee>(new Parameters
        {
            startDate = startDate, endDate = endDate
        });
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        connection.Disconnect();


        Console.WriteLine();
```